# How to use RSA to decrypt (not verify) data with a public key?

Tags: .net, encryption, rsa

I have an .Net application and I'm working on a licensing module. 
My Licence should look like the following string : **"from:01/01/2014:to:01/01/2016"**
That means that the licence allows using my application from Jan 2014 to Jan 2016.

To reduce (not eliminate) the risk of having my application easily hacked, I'm using RSA algorithm in order to encrypt my licence string with a private key (not available at the application level) and decrypt it with a public key that will be stored somewhere in the application.

By digging more in RSAServeProvider class, I see that only verifying data can be done with a public key (not decrypting). However some information are not available at the application to be verified.

Example :

In my application let's assume the following algorithm :

1- Read the licence file

2- Decrypt the licence file

3- Get the date stored in the licence file

4- Compare it with the current date

5- If current date is before date in the licence, go ahead, else exit

The step 3 is actualy not possible, because RSA allows only the verification of the licence with a value that is already available at the application : 
for example : checking if the licence file is identical to Jan 2016 (and not getting the value of the licence file whatever it's)

Does anyone know how to decrypt data using RSA public key only ?

Here is some code I'm using from MSDN :

```
        Dim ByteConverter As New ASCIIEncoding

        Dim dataString As String = "Data to Sign" 

        ' Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data. 
        Dim originalData As Byte() = ByteConverter.GetBytes(dataString)
        Dim signedData() As Byte 

        ' Create a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class  
        ' and automatically create a new key-pair. 
        Dim RSAalg As New RSACryptoServiceProvider

        Dim PrivateKey As RSAParameters = RSAalg.ExportParameters(True)
        Dim PublicKey as RSAParameters = RSAalg.ExportParameters(False)

        ' Hash and sign the data.
        signedData = HashAndSignBytes(originalData, PrivateKey )

        ' Verify the data and display the result to the console
        If VerifySignedHash(originalData, signedData, PublicKey) Then
            Console.WriteLine("The data was verified.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The data does not match the signature.")
        End If
```

And if I do

```
    RSA = New RSACryptoServiceProvider
    RSA.ImportParameters(PublicKey)
    Dim DecryptedData As Byte() = RSA.Decrypt(Data, False)
```

I recieve the error : **Additional information: Key does not exist.**

Thank you in advance

Comment: And why can't you use the verification part instead? Simply tuck on a signature to your license and verify that the license is unmodified at runtime.

Comment: I can not use the verification, because the string to verify is not known in advance. I'm not trying to match two strings. I'm trying to get values that I don't know from the crypted text.

Comment: How about simply reading the values out of unencrypted text instead? Why do you need to hide the details of the license?

Comment: The details of the license should be hidden because based on that the use my application will be controlled. If a user paid only for one year, the application should work only one year. This is why should not see what is hidden behind the licence string...

Comment: But why *hide* that information from him? I mean, it shouldn't be news or unknown to him that he paid for one year, so why not just write that out in cleartext in the license? Why the need to *hide* that particular part of the information, since it is already known?

Comment: Here's what I would do. I would write out the license information as a text file, line by line, readable text. Could be your own format, could be XML, could be JSON. At the bottom of the text file, you attach a signature. This signature is computed by taking all the text lines so far (the license), computing a hash for them using the private key, and signing that hash. This signature is attached to the bottom. Then, to verify, read the license, read the signature, recompute the hash from the license, and verify that the signature matches the hash using the public key. No need to hide anything.

Answer (score -4):

Basically when you use RSA you encrypt using the **public** key, while you decrypt using the **private** key. You're doing the reverse.

Comment: encrypting with private key and decrypting with the public is the goal. Think about a software licence. If you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the public, then cracking the software is trivial, because the private key will be stored somewhere in the software...

Comment: Your goal can't redefine how RSA works ;-) You have to define your problem/goal with how the crypto primitive works - i.e. this is not how software license are protected (and yes most kind of DRM are very bad ways to uses crypto).

Comment: RSA *math* works both ways. You can encrypt with one key and decrypt with the other. The *convention* is to only allow encryption with the public and decryption with the private, and signing with the private and verification with the public, but the *math* works equally fine both ways. There are also some subtle implementation details, more information can be found [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/do-public-private-pairs-work-both-ways). Additionally, other public-key encryption algorithms doesn't work like this, and libraries thus tends to implement it uniformly.

Comment: True but it's not *math* question and the .NET API (tag) won't allow this. I agree the problem definition needs to be changed (to solve it), but that was not the question either.